# Kendo Grid - Copy datasource from one grid to another

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a requirement to copy values from one grid datasource to another grid data source, but grid both schema are different. 
As we can find out from the bellow example as in, Grid One - only 3 columns are present and Grid Two - 4 columns. Here I need to copy data from Grid Two (COL4, COL2,COL3) and bind to Grid One without page refresh.

```
 Grid One 

    COL4 COL2 COL3
    XX    YY  ZZ
    zz    xy  SS

Grid Two
 COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
  XX    YY  ZZ   SA
  zz    AD  SS   DA
```

For reference, i have used bellow code, here it copying all the elements from GridTwo to GridOne, but i need specific columns like (COL4, COL2,COL3).

```
 gridTwo.select().each(function () {
        var dataItem = gridTwo.dataItem($(this));
        gridOne.dataSource.add(dataItem);        
    });
    gridOne.refresh();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried so far and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your reply, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new DataSource.

```
var data = [];

gridTwo.select().each(function () {
    var dataItem = gridTwo.dataItem($(this));
    data.push({ COL4: dataItem.COL4, COL2: dataItem.COL2, COL3: dataItem.COL3 });      
});

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   data: data
});

gridOne.setDataSource(ds);
gridOne.dataSource.read();
```